# Does Jinx AoE on her rockets work with Runaan's projectiles?

Tags: league-of-legends

Jinx deal AoE damage with her auto-attack when rockets are toggled on.

Does this AoE transfer to the Runaan's projectiles too?

If so, can same target be hit by the AoE of several projectiles?

Comment: Jinx is not yet a released champion. Therefore I think this question is offtopic.

Comment: @ColinD Jinx is released in PBE.

Comment: @3ventic did not know it was available in the PBE. However, I do not know how volatile the mechanics are on the PBE, so there is still a chance this question is not practically answerable/offtopic. related meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available

Comment: @ColinD "so there is still a chance this question is not practically answerable/offtopic" is one of the more silly things you can say about a question that is already ANSWERED.

Comment: @Wertilq having an answer says nothing about the quality/relevancy of the question or answer. If the mechanic is changing often enough the question is not practically answerable, because the answer changes constantly. Having an answer for a specific instance in time does not change that.

Comment: @ColinD while I agree on your stance with an unreleased game, whole of league is a constantly updated game. EVERYTHING in the game is for a specific instance in time. Champs are remade, items and abilities are changed and removed. There is not really a big enough difference between PBE and the live game. Just that things change slightly faster in PBE, your stance is that Debian Unstable doesn't need a wiki, while Testing does, because things might change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Runaan's work with her Q, the miniprojectiles from Runaan's all proc the AoE damage.

Notice in the test video that an explosion happens each minion hit by any of the projectiles. The AoE damage can also crit, near doubling her damage output.

[Note from creator of the champion](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3898293&page=28#post41884110)

> Rocket splash on individual Hurricane bolts is equal to the bolt's
>   damage (50% AD) and can not crit. A single target hit by splash from
>   the main attack and both hurricane bolts will take 210% damage (110%
>   from main attack + 2x50% for the Hurricane bolts.